# Ошибка с импортом библиотеки в vs code

Tags: python, telegram-bot

я сказал библиотеку telebot но когда я её импортирую, она подчёркивается желтым
так же вылезает ошибка "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'telebot'"
[image]

Comment: Значит библиотека не установлена в выбранное виртуальное окружение (оно указано справа внизу в окне vscode)

Comment: Потому что вы еще и не ту библиотеку установили, нужно устанавливать pytelegrambotapi